# Perform a segue when HTML link is touched

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, storyboard

I have some HTML content in my app using UIWebView.  I'd like to have a link in the HTML content that trigger my app to perform a segue or load another view controller.

For example, if I have some HTML content that includes the text "Check out our current specials", I want to use an  tag to enable "specials" to load the Specials view controller from the storyboard.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have code to show you but I believe I can show you the right direction because I have had to do this before.  Here is a way to do it.

1. In the hyperlink create a link that has a unique scheme name and path.  For example use MyScheme://GoToThisScreen/Identifier.
2. Set the UIWebView delegate to your file owner and ensure the file owner implement UIWebViewDelegate.
3. Override the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: and examine the URLRequest that comes from the web view.  If it is not your scheme (MyScheme) then you can let it pass through.
4. If it is your scheme you can use it to determine you next step.  For example segue to another screen.
5. Use the UIStoryBoard method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: where the identifier is assigned to the scene you wish to instantiate (last part of URI).  Remember you must get the correct storyboard to use this.
6. Push the View Controller you received in step 5 into the navigation controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed the steps you've provided and everything works quite well but I seem to be having an issue with the resulting view controller.  I have a menu similar to the menu in the Facebook app.  I am using the ECSlidingViewController class to create it.  When I present my view controller using your steps above, my menu button doesn't work.  At first I thought it was because I was using a generic UIViewController object for my instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method but I've changed the code to declare the view controller correctly and it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not really.  It appears you're either missing a link or the reference to the view controller may have been lost.